# Log debug messages in a SQL CLR C# Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, c#, sql-clr

I have developed a SQL CLR stored procedure in C#, for SQL Server 2012.

I want to log messages to SQL Server registers. On a normal stored procedure I use [`xp_logevent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186244.aspx)

What can I use to log a message in a SQL CLR stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just execute `xp_logevent` via `SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend()` in your `catch` block?

Comment: Yes, you are right but I thought that there is another better method to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel I cannot think of another method to do this, let alone a better one. Even if you did write to the Windows Event Log, I don't see how you would be able to write to the SQL Server Event Log from SQLCLR.